# Divide range to bins according to specific distribution in R

Tags: r, split, distribution, seq

I have ranges of numbers, for example 1-20000, and I have a vector of windows sizes:

```
lens <- c(100, 100, 100, 50, 20)
```

I would like to split the range 1-20000 to windows, where the distributions of the windows lengths will be similar to the one in the vector lengths.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I follow.  By "similar to", do you mean proportional to the vector lengths?  So for your example, your 20000 items would be split into buckets of size (say) 5405, 5405, 5405, 2703, 1082 - so the 4th bucket is about half the size of the 1st, and the 5th bucket is about 1/5 the size of the 1st?

Comment: This is exactly what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. First we need reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(20000, 200, replace=TRUE)
```

You want to divide the data into groups proportional to `lens`:

```
brks <- round(c(0, cumsum(lens)/sum(lens) * 20000))
brks
# [1]     0  5405 10811 16216 18919 20000
groups <- cut(x, brks, labels=brks[-1])
table(groups)
# groups
#  5405 10811 16216 18919 20000 
#    58    55    55    24     8
```